# Variety of commutative semi group

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra

V is a variety of commutative semi group satisfying the identity $x^2 = x^3$. 
I need to prove that:
$|F_V(\{x_1\dots,x_n\})|$ = $3^n -1$.
Any hints on this ?

$F_V$ is V-free algebra.

Comment: Judging from the result that you expect, I'm suspecting that you are after the variety of a commutative semigroup ring?  Maybe one that satisfies $x_i^2 = x_i^3$ for each indeterminate $x_i$?  Please rework this questions, at the moment it makes no sense.

Comment: @Thomas I suspect you are confusing identities and relations.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin You are right, I have no idea what the difference between an identity and a relation may be in the context here.

Comment: Regarding the question on hold.

Comment: Regarding the question on hold. I felt that this question uses advance math and users on Math SE wont be too responsive. I am gonna add the second part to this which I found in a paper I was reading. Kindly keep this here

Comment: It is phrased in terms of advanced mathematics, but its solution is accessible to students in high school.  Have you tried determining the structure of the algebra even for small values of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n = F_V(\{x_1, ..., x_n\})$. Since $S_n$ is commutative, its elements can be written in the form $x_1^{r_1} \cdots x_n^{r_n}$ where $r_1 + \dots + r_n > 0$. Morevover, since the semigroup $S_n$ satisfies the identity $x^2 = x^3$, you may assume that each $r_i$ is equal to $0$, $1$ or $2$. It follows that $|S_n| \leqslant 3^n -1$. To prove that this inequality is in fact an equality, it suffices to verify that the set of size $3^n -1$
$$
\{x_1^{r_1} \cdots x_n^{r_n} \mid 0 \leqslant r_i \leqslant 2 \text{ and } r_1 + \dots + r_n > 0\}
$$
equipped with the product defined by
$$
(x_1^{r_1} \cdots x_n^{r_n})(x_1^{s_1} \cdots x_n^{s_n}) = x_1^{\min\{2, r_1 + s_1\}} \cdots x_n^{\min\{2, r_n + s_n\}}
$$
is a semigroup of $V$.